# Unable to read data from object using gson and retrofit

Tags: java, android, arrays, object, gson

The server currently returns a json which looks like the json given below, it contains a field called `data` which is an array of arrays with each array having multiple objects and each object having a key called `item_type`. The key `item_type` allows me to figure out exactly what type of object it is so that I can cast it accordingly in java but I am unable to read the `item_type` field.

```
{  
   "page":1,
   "data":[  
      [  
         {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"xyz",
            "item_type":1
         }
      ],
      [  
         {  
            "cid":1,
            "item_type":2
         }
      ],
      [  
         {  
            "item":1,
            "item_type":3
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

The retrofit interface is like so

```java
    @GET("Search")
        Observable<SearchResults> search(@Query(ParamsHolder.GET_QUERY) 
    String query, @Query(ParamsHolder.GET_PAGE) int page);
```

where the `SearchResults` class looks like this

```java
public class SearchResults {

    int page;

    List<List<Object>> data;

    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public List<List<Object>> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

I am able to fetch the data fine but I need to read the objects that are inside each list. In order to do that I used the following code

```java
public class SearchItem {

  int item_type;

  public int getItemType() {
      return item_type;
  }
}

List<List<Object>> data = objects.getData();

for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {

  List<Object> list = data.get(i);

  for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {

    SearchItem item = (SearchItem) list.get(i);

    Log.d("search", " json=" + list.get(j).toString());
    Log.d("search", " item=" + item.toString() + " type=" + item.getItemType());
    }

}
```

I created a dummy `SearchItem` class which I assumed would let me typecast the `Object` type so I could read the `item_type` which would let me know exactly the type of object this is.

It throws an error `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to in.example.models.SearchItem`

The end goal here it to be able to cast each object in the array to the correct type and the only way I can do that is by reading the `item_type` key in the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Gson to directly parse the response

Update SearchResults

```
 public class SearchResults {

    int page;

    List<List<SearchItem>> data;

    public int getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public List<List<SearchItem>> getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

You can access item_type like this

```
searchResult.getData.get(i).get(0).item_type
```

Answer (score 1):

use Response as a return type in your interface retrofit function as shown below

```
@GET("Search")
Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> search(@Query(ParamsHolder.GET_QUERY) 
              String query, @Query(ParamsHolder.GET_PAGE) int page);
```

this way you can retrieve the full json body  and you have now full control on how parse the data based on item_type

so basically you call function  `response.body().string()`  to get the json body

and than you parse manually like shown below:

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

            //looping through the data array 
            for(int i = 0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                JSONArray  childArr = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
             //looping through current child array inside data 
                  for(int j = 0;j<childArr .length();j++){
                   JSONObject nestedChildObj =childArr.getJSONObject(j);
                   //now i have access to item_type
                   int item_type =  nestedChildObj .getInt("item_type")
                   //now you can use gson to parse the nestedChildObj based 
                   //on item_type or manually do the parsing
                 }
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```